# store_accessor not reading value in JSON field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have the a db table:

```
create_table :events do |t|
   t.string :event_type, null: false
   t.json :data, default: {}

   t.timestamps null: false
end
```

And the following model:

```
class Event < ApplicationRecord
   store_accessor :data, :member_id

   before_validation :populate_data
   validates :member_id, presence: true

   private

   def populate_data
     self.data[:member_id] = 123
   end
end
```

When trying to save a record, the validations fail with `member id - cannot be blank`. However, as you can see, I'm giving `member_id` a value before validations take place.

Am I missing something? It seems like this should work to me. If I manually force create a record, I can call `Event.last.member_id` and it returns the correct value, so it clearly *can* read the value from the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had similar experience with you before.

I solved it by using string instead of symbol.

You can try this

```
  def populate_data
    self.data['member_id'] = 123
  end
```

Or maybe better to use accessor like this

```
  def populate_data
    self.member_id = 123
  end
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to fix it.